# Amazon Managed Airflow 2.2.2 Fails To Run Tasks From The CLI With DeprecationWarning

Tags: amazon-web-services, airflow, mwaa

## Context

I am upgrading our system from Amazon Managed Airflow 2.0.2 to 2.2.2. I am running into a situation where I can run DAGs in the UI but if I try to run them from the API I'm hitting

```
/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py:357 DeprecationWarning: The default_queue option in [celery] has been moved to the default_queue option in [operators] - the old setting has been used, but please update your config.
```

I'm trying to figure out what could be causing this problem or even what my next steps to debug this issue are.

## DAGs Running In UI

The dag in this example is failing but that's not what I'm focused on currently. I can't even get the dags to start from the CLI.
[image]

## Example MWAA CLI Call

```
% curl --request POST "https://$WEB_SERVER_HOSTNAME/aws_mwaa/cli" -sS --header "Authorization: Bearer $CLI_TOKEN" --header "Content-Type: text/plain" --data-raw "$OPERATION"
{"stderr":"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","stdout":"ZW52X2Rldl9tYWluCg=="}
% echo "L3Vzci9sb2NhbC9haXJmbG93Ly5sb2NhbC9saWIvcHl0aG9uMy43L3NpdGUtcGFja2FnZXMvYWlyZmxvdy9jb25maWd1cmF0aW9uLnB5OjM1NyBEZXByZWNhdGlvbldhcm5pbmc6IFRoZSBkZWZhdWx0X3F1ZXVlIG9wdGlvbiBpbiBbY2VsZXJ5XSBoYXMgYmVlbiBtb3ZlZCB0byB0aGUgZGVmYXVsdF9xdWV1ZSBvcHRpb24gaW4gW29wZXJhdG9yc10gLSB0aGUgb2xkIHNldHRpbmcgaGFzIGJlZW4gdXNlZCwgYnV0IHBsZWFzZSB1cGRhdGUgeW91ciBjb25maWcuCi91c3IvbG9jYWwvYWlyZmxvdy8ubG9jYWwvbGliL3B5dGhvbjMuNy9zaXRlLXBhY2thZ2VzL2FpcmZsb3cvY29uZmlndXJhdGlvbi5weTozNTcgRGVwcmVjYXRpb25XYXJuaW5nOiBUaGUgZGVmYXVsdF9xdWV1ZSBvcHRpb24gaW4gW2NlbGVyeV0gaGFzIGJlZW4gbW92ZWQgdG8gdGhlIGRlZmF1bHRfcXVldWUgb3B0aW9uIGluIFtvcGVyYXRvcnNdIC0gdGhlIG9sZCBzZXR0aW5nIGhhcyBiZWVuIHVzZWQsIGJ1dCBwbGVhc2UgdXBkYXRlIHlvdXIgY29uZmlnLgo=" | base64 --decode
/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py:357 DeprecationWarning: The default_queue option in [celery] has been moved to the default_queue option in [operators] - the old setting has been used, but please update your config.
/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py:357 DeprecationWarning: The default_queue option in [celery] has been moved to the default_queue option in [operators] - the old setting has been used, but please update your config.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue ended up being a problem with the MWAA 2.2.2 CLI API where the warning was returned on stderr but no actual error occurred. I ended up adding

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    if [[ $line != *"DeprecationWarning"* ]]; then
        ACTUAL_ERROR=1
        break
    fi
done <<< "$ERRORS"
```

To our shell scripts and

```
std_err = base64.b64decode(response.json()["stderr"]).decode("utf8").splitlines()
if std_err:
    for line in std_err:
        if "DeprecationWarning" not in line:
            raise ValueError(f"Hit an Airflow error with err message: {std_err}")
```

to our Python scripts and this solved our core issue.